# XPATH to select child elements that contain the entire text node of the parent element

Tags: xml, xpath

I am looking for an XPATH expression that selects child nodes whenever it contains the entire text node of the parent element.
e.g.:

```
<title><italic>Here is my title</italic></title>
```

(here I want to select italic as it includes the entire content of its parent.
but I don't want to select:

```
<title>Here is my <italic>italic</italic> title</title>
```

or

```
<title><bold>Here is my </bold><italic>italic title</italic></title>
```

(here, italic only contains part of the parents text)

Any ideas?
Thanks!
Franziska

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
/*//*[. = ..]
```

will select all elements beneath the root element whose string value equals that of its parent.

So, for this XML,

```
<r>
  <title><italic>Here is my title</italic></title>
  <title>Here is my <italic>italic</italic> title</title>
  <title><bold>Here is my </bold><italic>italic title</italic></title>
  <title><italic><bold>Another</bold></italic><italic> case</italic></title>
</r>
```

the following elements,

```
<italic>Here is my title</italic>    
<bold>Another</bold>
```

will be selected.

Comment: Sorry for not being really clear on my requirements, but the XPath you just added works perfectly fine. Thanks a lot!